# Какой регуляркой вывести текст до запятой с пробелом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка: *ул. Академика Бочвара, 2*.

Как вывести: *ул. Академика Бочвара*?

Comment: Наверн так: [^,\n]

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось? Какой диалект?

Comment: Для какого языка программирования нужна регулярка? Например, на php или JavaScript, регулярка для решения данной задачи не нужна вообще.

Comment: String result = new String("ул. Академика Бочвара, 2"); result = result.substring(0,result.indexOf(", "));

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, для php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/(.+)(?:,)/`

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/dqtlz1/1/)

Без регулярки

`$matches = explode(", ", "ул. Академика Бочвара, 2.");
var_dump($matches);`